# mixed integer quadratic programming in python

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization

I was wondering if someone could give me some guidance in setting up my objective.

I am trying to minimise variance in python with some cardinality constraints on the number of assets in my portfolio. I am not sure what package would help me do this. And if there was a working example for the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a MIQP model that illustrates how we can model a portfolio problem with the number assets limited to be between *minAssets* and *maxAssets*. If an asset is in the portfolio, furthermore its fraction is limited to be between *fmin* and *fmax*.

[image]

In this [link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/02/cardinality-constrained-portfolio.html) you can also see how you can try to solve this problem with just a series of linear MIP problems.

MIQP solvers are readily available: CVXPY/ECOS_BB, Cplex, and Gurobi are a few examples. These are all callable from Python. A simple portfolio QP model would be a good starting point (no doubt such a model is available in the examples for any of these solvers).

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at some links, which are about python package `CVXOPT`:

https://cvxopt.org/examples/book/portfolio.html

https://scaron.info/blog/quadratic-programming-in-python.html

Comment: thanks for this but I am trying to add cardinality constraints i dont think i can use cvxopt for this. If i can please can you point me to an example.  i am trying to limit the number of names preferably by group. For example in a 5 stock example I have 3 tech stocks and 2 non tech stocks I would like to limit each sector (tech and non tech) to have 2 stocks each

Comment: You mean that you want that each time some weights will be strongly equal to 0 ?

Comment: yes or have the flexibility to set hte lower bounds

Comment: in a typical minimum variance optimization, i have some long only constraints, i have a sum constraint equal to 1, and i have some sector sum constraints. I would like to incorporate the number of stock constraints

Comment: And based on what conditions you want to force some weights to be equal 0 ? I mean you will fix some condition for each portfolio rebalance ? I can suggest to fix some threshold of minimum weight and if for some asset weight is less than this threshold,  just replace it with 0 and correspondigly adjust other weights.